# giving a class object a value c#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, class

I have a class called playingcards it inherits from a cards class. I instantiated it as an object called chuckcards. One of the data members is CARD ID. I'm trying to assign a int to the value. it is declared public int the class.
Here's how its instantiated.

`playingcards[] chuckcards = new playingcards[10];`

Here is how I try to assign values.

```
for (int ctr = 1; ctr < 10; ctr++)
        {

            chuckcards[ctr].cardID =  ctr;

            temp++;
        }
```

The error I get is

> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong? Could I make a method that assigns the value to each member? if so that's gonna be a pain for certain things but I could do it? or is their a simple way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `new playingcards[10]`, it only creates placeholders which have the default of that type, which is `null` for reference types. You will have to actually new up playingcards to then use it

```
    for (int ctr = 1; ctr < 10; ctr++)
    {
        chuckcards[ctr] = new playcards{cardID=ctr};
        temp++;
    }
```

I used an object initializer to simplify the code down to one line also.

Here is what happens:

```
var chuckcards = new playingcards[10];
```

Results in the following:

```
chuckcards[0] = null
...
chuckcards[9] = null
```

So, you cannot do

```
chuckcards[0].cardID
```

because it is really

```
null.cardID
```

So, once you initialize the value it will have a reference from then on:

```
chuckcards[0] = new playingcards();
chuckcards[0].cardID = ctr;
```

evaluates to

```
[ref to playingcards].cardID
```

which is valid

Comment: Thank you. So I'm creating the indivdual instances? Would I have to new it up once then? Or say I went to do `chuckcards[0].cardName = "Chuck";` would I have todo that again? Any links for help with syntax too would be great :)

Comment: no, only on the initialization. I am adding to my answer to explain better

Comment: OK, hopefully the current answer explains it well enough for you

Comment: Thank you sir, its solved my issues that no-one coudl solve for me at uni. If this was reddit I'd buy you gold but I guess all I can offer is my extreme gratitude

Comment: And, you can give me the checkmark for accepted answer :) and now that you have 15 points, an upvote also :)

Answer (score 5):

You have defined an array of 10 slots to hold instances of playingcards, but every slot is still null
Before entering the loop you need to add an instance in every slot with

```
 chuckcards[0] = new  playingcards();
```

and so on..... (1,2,...9=max index)

eventually you could check inside the loop if you have assigned an instance to a particular slot or not

```
 for (int ctr = 0; ctr < 10; ctr++)
 {
    if(chuckcards[i] != null)
    {
        chuckcards[ctr].cardID =  ctr;
        temp++;
    }
 }
```

And remember, array index start at zero not at one

Answer (score 4):

You need to give `chuckcards[ctr]` an object instance:

```
chuckcards[ctr] = new playingcards();
chuckcards[ctr].cardID = ctr;
```

Answer (score 3):

chuckcards[ctr] is null, you have to instantiate it

```
playingcards[] chuckcards = new playingcards[10];

for (int ctr = 0; ctr < 10; ctr++)
{
   chuckcards[ctr] = new playingcards();
   chuckcards[ctr].cardID =  ctr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The chuckcards[ctr] is null. You need to instanciate it.

```
for (int ctr = 1; ctr < 10; ctr++)
{
    chuckcards[ctr] = new playingcards();
    chuckcards[ctr].cardID =  ctr;
    temp++;
}
```

To have less code, you can make another constructor that need an id. Then you have :

```
for (int ctr = 1; ctr < 10; ctr++)
{
    chuckcards[ctr] = new playingcards(ctr);
    temp++;
}
```