# Dequeueing an class and individual values c#

Tags: c#, arrays, class, queue

This is a follow up from yesterday's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193052/giving-a-class-object-a-value-c-sharp)
I have 2 queue, they contain 5 elements each called player 1 and player 2.
They were queued using something like the following

```
player2.Enqueue(chuckcards[i]);
```

Chuck cards is a class that has several different data members including 6 ints and one string. Now I wish to dequeue one item give the values to a labels (Multipul one per data member) and the string to a picture box (I don't need help with that). But I would like to know how I get the values from the dequeue. I would also like to be able to say re queue on the other players queue. So I might use the peak operation to get the values then if the outcome is successful just move it off the end of queue 1 and onto queue 2.

Hope that's clear.

Any help would be appreciated. I have searched around but found no real answer yet.

Comment: `var card = player2.Dequeue();`? You might want to check if `player2.Count > 0`. If you `Peek()` an empty `Queue` you will get an exception. "Requeue" is the same as `Enqueue(card)`.

Comment: Oh okay thank you for the tip. I'll implement some form of checking :) I don't think the game will continue when the queue is empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
Queue<Foo> firstQueue = new Queue<Foo>();
Queue<Foo> secondQueue = new Queue<Foo>();
//todo populate
var item = firstQueue.Dequeue();
item.DoStuff();
secondQueue.Enqueue(item);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but surely the var would only store a single value? I have several data members in the class? Could I say call one item at a time? E.g `var item1 = firstQueue.Dequeue(item1);`? or is that not possible

Comment: @Yop That one item returned is the class that holds all of the data.  You can then freely access all of the members of that one item to get the various aspects of data that you want.  `Dequeue` takes no parameters; you cannot give it any, nor can I see what you expect to change as a result of what you pass in.

Comment: I think I get what you are saying. I'm going to try and implement it now and I'll ask follow questions if thats okay?

Comment: Okay I Implemented and Looking in the locals at a breakpoint I get what I'm doing. But Obviously, I can't type `int ID = item.CARDID();` because it doesn't know that item contains the id of the card at compilation. How do I go around that?

Comment: @Yop You haven't provided enough information about your code to answer that question.

Comment: @Yop Telling me that before you've done it doesn't help anything.

Comment: Okay changed the post, any idea. I'm not really sure how else I can provide any more information

Comment: Looks like your problem is that you're typing `CARDID()` instead of `cardID`, which is the actual field name.  It's not a method, and it's case sensitive.  Also note that it's bad practice to expose fields publicly.  You should use methods or properties to expose information publicly.

Comment: I understand where I went wrong now by not using a abstract class version of my Queue. Queue<playingcards>